# Eclipse Perl Debugging - Conditional Breakpoints?

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, conditional-statements, epic

Does the perl debugger for Ecipse, EPIC, support conditional breakpoints yet? If so could someone tell me how to add one as all the documentation I've read says nothing about conditional breakpoints in perl.  I see them for the Java debugger but not for Perl. Or they aren't supported, is there a way to add one manually? For example, continue running script until $var = 10008, then allow me to step through the code.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't tested this, but `$DB::single = 1 if $var == 10008;` at the desired location should work.

Comment: watchpoints are probably what you're looking for.

Comment: the $DB::single = 1 if $var == 10008; doesn't work, it just keeps running

Comment: for the watchpoints, if I do `DB<1> w` then how would I make that conditional?

Answer (score 0):

[Devel::Trepan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan) has gdb-style conditional breakpoints. Perhaps there is or someone will write an Eclipse plugin.